# simulate "Add to Home Screen" feature on older iPod touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPod Touch 1.1.4, and want to experiment with creating minimalistic "apps" just by scripting, launching Safari to a "webapp". But 1.1.4 does not have the "Add to Home Screen" shortcut option. Is there a way to simulate this just by scripting? I've tried editing the HelloPython Bash script, changing it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari http://gnixl.com/
```

And I get the error:

```
ABORT: Unable to register "com.apple.mobilesafari" port, 1103 unknown error code.
```

I removed the URL http://gnixl.com/, same error.

Is there a way to do this without using Python or Objective-C? Not that I'm not willing to use either/or, but I'm looking for the most barebones approach that will do *something* first.

If someone with a newer iPod touch could "add to home screen" anything and analyze what it puts into the Applications folder, that might be just the info I need. Or if someone jailbroke their device with ziphone and left the link on the homescreen, that would work too unless the "link" is actually an executable.

[update 2016-01-25: 2 github projects now up using troutinator's answer as template: https://github.com/jcomeauictx/conwaylife and https://github.com/jcomeauictx/taillight]

Comment: I believe it's possible because ziphone left a link on the homescreen, which I foolishly deleted  in a "housekeeping" frenzy.

Comment: What do you mean by creating minimalistic app? You want, by scripting, create an app similar to when you press the "Add to Home Screen" menu?

Comment: @Guillaume: the webapps I know how to make. what I don't know is how to make a home-screen shortcut to launch MobileSafari to my app. so yes, I want to find out how to do what "add to home screen" does, at the filesystem level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have an iPhone 3G. I created an link from Safari using the "Add To Home Screen" button. It created a directory called `54C86B09482D4560BAB46091CC75825A.webclip` inside of `/private/var/mobile/Library/WebClips/`. That directory contains two files, `icon.png`and `Info.plist`. `icon.png` is simply the icon that gets shown when looking at the apps screen.

The contents of `Info.plist` are where the real information is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>ClassicMode</key>
        <false/>
        <key>FullScreen</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IconIsPrecomposed</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IconIsScreenShotBased</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Scale</key>
        <real>0.32653060555458069</real>
        <key>ScrollPoint</key>
        <dict>
                <key>x</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
                <key>y</key>
                <real>-183</real>
        </dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>The Daily WTF</string>
        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleGray</string>
        <key>URL</key>
        <string>http://thedailywtf.com/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

*Edit: Fixed some grammar, clarified things a bit, and added the test/example below:*

So, to test this out I created a new folder called `C28C8FDC2F184AAD84F77B511442548F.webclip` and copied the `Info.plist` file over from the other directory, edited the url to `http://google.com`. I then re-sprung the phone and it showed up just like any other webclip. The folder name is simply a hex encoded GUID, I used `http://www.somacon.com/p113.php` and just selected what was after 0x for this simple test

Comment: thank you! awesome, just what I needed! it crashes my MobileSafari, but otherwise it works. maybe because I didn't use a GUID, just "test.webclip". but it shows up on my desktop just fine. much appreciated!

Comment: thought that accepting it would give you the bounty, but then I noticed it didn't... looks like you got it now! thanks again.

Comment: by editing the Info.plist, I've gotten to where I have something that doesn't crash MobileSafari.

Comment: Glad to help out, and glad that its working without crashing for you.