# Save webpage link on iPhone's desktop programmatically

Tags: jquery, iphone, asp.net, jqtouch

In order to save a direct web link on iPhone's desktop, I use to browse desired webpage on safari and, once loaded, press middle button and then save to desktop option. I would like to do the same programmatically using jqtouch, jquery or any other asp method. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked a few times on SO, but I'll just sum it up anyway.

If you're developing for **non-jailbroken** iPhones, then the answer is NO. But there is an altervative: see [Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone).

If your audience are **jailbroken** iPhones, that's another story. The following post explains the solution: [simulate "Add to Home Screen" feature on older iPod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075280/simulate-add-to-home-screen-feature-on-older-ipod-touch).